# css selector not working without its class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="one">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>one text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>one text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This css won't work

```
#header ul.menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two ul{                     /*this line*/
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

This css work

```
#header ul.menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two ul.menu{                /*this line*/
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/M5pLZ/)

Why is this so?

**Update**

As per answers on css specificity `#header ul.menu` is more specific than `#two ul`. I got it carefully ul.menu is more specific than ul.

```
ul.menu{...}
#two ul{...} /* works exactly, yes #two is more specific than ul.menu */
```

---

Okay, Change the order

**order 1:**

```
#header ul.menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two ul.menu{                   /* this selector works as per the specificity */
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Why `#two ul.menu` is more specific than `#header ul.menu`? (Demo is not required for this as top first demo shows this)

**order 2:**

```
#two ul.menu{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
#header ul.menu{                /* this selector works as per the specificity */
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Why `#header ul.menu` is more specific than `#two ul.menu`? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/M5pLZ/5/)

Comment: Read more about CSS specificity [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the class selector in `#header ul.menu` makes it more specific than `#two ul`, even though `#two` is "closer" to the `ul` in terms of structure. Specificity doesn't care how "close" one element is to another. It doesn't even count combinators, so even if you used `#two > ul` it wouldn't make a difference.

If you're going to select the same element, there is no reason not to balance your selector for specificity and either keep the class selector in both rules:

```
#header ul.menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two ul.menu{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Or remove it from both rules:

```
#header ul{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two ul{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Depending on your needs.

---

In your update you've simply switched the two equally specific rules around. The later rule always overrides the earlier rule. Again, this is regardless of element structure.

Comment: it means ul.menu is more specific than ul.

Comment: @C-Link: You don't change your question or "mind" like that and unaccept my answer just because it doesn't answer your new question. If you have a different question, post it as new. But I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt here so I've updated my answer.

Comment: If you don't mind please explain properly that I could understand.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the first selector:

```
#header ul.menu
```

Is a more specific match than:

```
#two ul
```

Because it contains a class selector as well as a type selector, therefore will be overriden by the styles applied using the top selector.

Comment: agree. One more thing you can notice if you use #two ul and remove menu class from second ul. This will also work. Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/M5pLZ/4/

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have the line `#header ul.menu` which is more 'specific' so it uses those styles. Either use `#one ul` instead `#header ul` or use `#two ul.menu`

Answer (score 0):

`#header ul.menu`sets the background color for all `ul.menu` items in your DOM tree beneath `#header`. So it has a higher css weight as opposed to `#header ul` or `#two ul`

Look at how cascading in css actually works and how the weighing is applied.

You could also run without any `ul` and just use the `#id .class` and it would work.

```
#header .menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
#two .menu{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why `#header ul.menu` is more specific than `#two ul.menu`?

The selectors have the ***same*** specificity. When this happens, the one that was declared last wins.

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same
>   weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.
>   Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>   declarations in the style sheet itself.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Answer (score -1):

You should mention full heirarchy, like `#header div ul.menu`

The following will work :

```
#header div ul.menu{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Then if you want a particular div inside the `header` to have different css styles, replace `div` with the id or unique class of that particular div.

```
#header #two ul.menu{
    //some styles just for menu inside #two
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/M5pLZ/3/

Cheers